# Hbase Row filtering doesn't work

Tags: java, hbase

I have a Hbase table where my row key looks like as below mentioned

```
        12345678912:::timestamp:::1234567891:::john         cf:somedata
        12345678912:::timestamp:::1234567891:::smith        cf:somedata
        12345678912:::timestamp:::1234567891:::lotta        cf:somedata
```

Now, i want to filter out some rows using row key regex like as mentioned below

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW=>'.*:::starttimestamp:::.*:::john', STOPROW=>'.*:::endtimestamp:::.*:::john'}
```

But this doesn't seem to work either and i understood that we cannot use regex in rowkey by some study.

How can i use FuzzyRowFilter for this operation in hbase shell? Does this filter really help in my case?

I know that i can use SingleColumnValue filter for specific rows but my row key also matter here for me.

Comment: So you need all rows for john in row key and between two timestamps?

Comment: Yes so far i tried this but this does not work correctly on getting record between two timestamps

scan 'mytable', {FILTER => RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),RegexStringComparator.new('^\d{1,}:::([startingtimestamp-endingtimestamp]*):::.*:::john'))}

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is range scan on row key. 
It looks like, the range works for the entire string. For example, the following works.

```
scan 'scanRangeTest',{STARTROW=>'1234|20-10-2014|john', STOPROW=>'1234|24-10-2014|john'}
```

You will get all records for john between two timestamps. Point here is you should build the start and stop parameters.

There is a regex comparator. You can use it with RowKey Filter. Refer [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html). However, when you use regex in that manner, you will get all records which match, but it would not give you the range option, which might be important to you.

Alternatives to above 'rowfilter with regex comparator' are secondary indexes, and [FuzzyRowFilter](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/). These help in getting faster scans by skipping certain records. However, the range option is still not there. So you can take your call based on your requirement.

Solution to your problem

Get date range and for a specific user name(john), and some id's(12345678912, 1234567891). In my scan command, range works only for full row key and not regex. So as long as you have the name and id's common(you can get this params as usual) and then only change the time stamp(you can add this as your requirement), and using all three, you build entire row key, then u can use start and stop row. I hope I cleared your requirement.

```
create 'scanRangeTest', {NAME => 'srt', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1'}
put 'scanRangeTest','1234|20-10-2014|john', 'srt:name','John Details'
put 'scanRangeTest','1235|21-10-2014|smita', 'srt:name','Smita Details'
put 'scanRangeTest','1236|22-10-2014|lotta', 'srt:name','Lotta Details'
put 'scanRangeTest','1234|23-10-2014|john', 'srt:name','John Details sec timestamp'
put 'scanRangeTest','1237|23-10-2014|john', 'srt:name','Ram Details'

scan 'scanRangeTest',{STARTROW=>'1234|20-10-2014|john', STOPROW=>'1234|24-10-2014|john'}

Output
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL
 1234|20-10-2014|john                    column=srt:name, timestamp=1446045032763, value=John Details
 1234|23-10-2014|john                    column=srt:name, timestamp=1446045054544, value=John Details sec timestamp
```

Comment: The range check is not working in case of row filter and fuzzyrowfilter and the regex will not work in case of startrow and stoprow hence your inputs are not helpful.

Comment: Thats what I said above. You have only range scan with complete row key which is working.. Please read the above comment again. I mentioned range wont work in response to your query about fuzzyrowfilter.

Comment: Ok, can I use regex in stoprow and startrow? See my initial post, you were nowhere using regex in your answer. Without regex combined with range scan on rowkey, I cannot seem to solve my problem.